# Android Service which runs every 10 seconds

Tags: android

I have a android application, which contains a main activity which displays information to the user.
When the main activity starts, A service is created which checks a web service every 10 seconds - if the WS return answer a notification is popped. There is no connection between the main activity and the service (except I want them to start together). the problem is the activty is working really slow - because the service is running.

How Should I fix it? I tried using IntentService but he died after 10 seconds.

The code I'm using:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {    

super.onCreate();
context = this.getApplicationContext();
mPeriodicEventHandler = new Handler();
mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT); 
}

private Runnable doPeriodicTask = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        NotificationServices.Notification();
        mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT);
    }
 };
```

Comment: 10 seconds is really fast, what if the connection is really slow?

Comment: Are you using Pending intent for notifying from the service?

Comment: @XepterX - This is only POC so it runs on our WiFi lab.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling i suggest you to use GCM i.e c2dm this is the scenario for which c2dm was designed...

for reference check these links you will be surely like to use this

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Handler is performing tasks in the main UI thread, that can affect your activity's UI or even cause ANRs.

I will suggest to create a new HandlerThread and post your task there.

However, be sure you really want to pull data every 10 seconds. It's costly for mobile internet and device power consumption.

Consider using [Persistent Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) or [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Hey,

This is POC - So we want to demonstraite GCM and Polling.

Should I create the handlerThread in the service?

Comment: Yes. create new HandlerThread("name"), call start(), wait it to be really started(there is a small delay between you called start() and it's really happened), and then getLooper() from this thread.
 
After it's done - just create your Handler with new Handler(thread.getLooper()) - at all the rest of the code will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Using Handler we can do this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer Foreground Service Controller example in [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) and update pending event whenever webservice is updated.

Also consider using [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .

I hope this helps :)